# sudo create_ap wlan0 wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase

Tags: kali-linux

```
┌──(em㉿em)-[~]
└─$ sudo create_ap wlan0 wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
Config dir: /tmp/create_ap.wlan0.conf.Jr1F43yn
PID: 120173
cp: warning: behavior of -n is non-portable and may change in future; use --update=none instead
cp: warning: behavior of -n is non-portable and may change in future; use --update=none instead
Network Manager found, set ap0 as unmanaged device... DONE
/usr/bin/create_ap: line 342: [[: 2457.0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0")
/usr/bin/create_ap: line 344: [[: 2457.0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0")
/usr/bin/create_ap: line 346: [[: 2457.0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0")
/usr/bin/create_ap: line 348: [[: 2457.0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0")
/usr/bin/create_ap: line 350: [[: 2457.0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0")
wlan0 is already associated with channel 0 (2457.0 MHz), fallback to channel 0
Creating a virtual WiFi interface... ap0 created.

ERROR: Your adapter can not transmit to channel 0, frequency band 2.4GHz.


Doing cleanup.. done
```

After upgrading the Kali, it did not work. Before the upgrade, it worked. What is the problem?